# Refer to inbox of second account

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to look through a specific inbox for unread e-mails with .pdf files attached to them, and then save them into a specific folder.

I need to look through the inbox of certain account profile. My code only works if there is just one Inbox folder and one account profile.

Let's say I have two profiles;

One is xxxx@hotmail.com

The second zzzz@hotmail.com

How do I run the code on the Inbox of the second account? 
(zzzz@hotmail.com)

The following is the code that I have so far;

```
Sub GetAttachments()
On Error GoTo GetAttachments_err

Dim ns As NameSpace
Dim Inbox As MAPIFolder
Dim Item As Object
Dim Atmt As Attachment
Dim FileName As String
Dim varResponse As VbMsgBoxResult

Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

i = 0

' Checks inbox for messages.
If Inbox.Items.Count = 0 Then
MsgBox "There are no messages in your Inbox.", vbInformation, _
"Nothing found"
Exit Sub
End If
' Checks inbox for unread messages.
If Inbox.UnReadItemCount = 0 Then
"Nothing found"
Exit Sub
End If

' Checks for unread messages with .pdf files attached to them, if yes         then saves it to specific folder. _
  Puts date and time from when the mail was created infront of the  filename.
For Each Item In Inbox.Items
For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
If Item.UnRead = True Then
If Right(Atmt.FileName, 3) = "pdf" Then
FileName = "C:\Users\XXX\Documents\Office Macro\" & _
Format(Item.CreationTime, "yyyymmdd_hhnnss_") & Atmt.FileName
Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName
i = i + 1
End If
End If
Next Atmt
Next Item

' Shows how many attached files there are if any are found.
If i > 0 Then
& vbCrLf & "Jag har sparat dem till C:\Users\XXX\Documents\Office Macro folder." _
& vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Would you like to see your files?" _
vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Finished!")
 If varResponse = vbYes Then
 Shell "Explorer.exe /e,C:\Users\XXX\Documents\Office Macro\", vbNormalFocus
End If
Else
MsgBox "No attached files could be found.", vbInformation, _
"Finished!"
End If

GetAttachments_exit:
   Set Atmt = Nothing
   Set Item = Nothing
   Set ns = Nothing
   Exit Sub

GetAttachments_err:
   MsgBox "An unkown ghost spooked the program." _
      & vbCrLf & "Please note and report the following information." _
      & vbCrLf & "Macro Name: GetAttachments" _
      & vbCrLf & "Error Number: " & Err.Number _
      & vbCrLf & "Error Description: " & Err.Description _
      , vbCritical, "Error!"
   Resume GetAttachments_exit

Exit Sub

End Sub
```

After further inspection of the mailboxes I see that there are some differences:

xxxx@hotmail.com is of the type "IMAP/SMTP"

zzzz@hotmail.com is of the type "Exchange ActiveSync"

I've also noticed that that the account ID I would need to use is 4, as seen in this code when sending a new message with a test-macro specifying what profile you want to send the mail from by assigning profile ID in the script:

```
Sub Mail_small_Text_Change_Account()
'Only working in Office 2007-2013
'Don't forget to set a reference to Outlook in the VBA editor
    Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strbody As String

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    strbody = "Hi there" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "This is line 1" & vbNewLine & _
              "This is line 2" & vbNewLine & _
              "This is line 3" & vbNewLine & _
              "This is line 4"

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "blabla@blabla.nl"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
        .Body = strbody

        'SendUsingAccount is new in Office 2007
        'Change Item(1)to the account number that you want to use
        .SendUsingAccount = OutApp.Session.Accounts.Item(4)   <<<< ACCOUNT ID

        .Send   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

You get only the delivery store's inbox folder to find the items.

The [Stores](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff864790(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Namespace class returns a Stores collection object that represents all the Store objects in the current profile. You can find the required store and then use the [GetDefaultFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869924(v=office.15).aspx) method of the Store class instead. This method is similar to the GetDefaultFolder method of the NameSpace object. The difference is that this method gets the default folder on the delivery store that is associated with the account, whereas NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder returns the default folder on the default store for the current profile.

```
 Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
 Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
```

There is no need to create a new Outlook Application instance in Outlook VBA.

The Outlook object model provides the [Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869662(v=office.15).aspx)/[FindNext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862482(v=office.15).aspx) or [Restrict](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869597(v=office.15).aspx) methods of the Items class. Also you may find the [AdvancedSearch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866933(v=office.15).aspx) method of the Application class helpful.

Comment: I appreciate the fast answer however, I'm completley new at programming and wouldn't know how to adjust the code I have with what you wrote. You think you could adjust the code in my original message as an example of how I should do it? Either way thanks a millions.